# Use one query of DataTable then apply filter

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datatable

I have two query into foreach clauses who returns data from datatable with filters:

```
 foreach (var currentDesignItem in designItemList.Select($"[Design Name] = '{designName}' AND [Project Number] = {legacyKey}  AND [DesignTypeName] <> 'Change Order'"))
```

And

```
 foreach (var item in designItemList.Select($"[Design Name] = '{designName}' AND [Project Number] = {legacyKey} AND [DesignTypeName] = 'Change Order'"))
```

As you can see it's same query but one different filter  `AND [DesignTypeName] = 'Change Order'.`

So I don't want to do query two times and I try

```
 DataRow[] dtList = designItemList.Select($"[Design Name] = '{designName}' AND [Project Number] = {legacyKey}");
```

then try to filter in foreach as:

```
foreach (var currentDesignItem in dtList.Select("[DesignTypeName] <> 'Change Order'"))
```

But I'm getting an error:

> The type arguments for method 'Enumerable.Select(IEnumerable, Func)' cannot be
>   inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.

Comment: `designItemList.Select` is a `DataTable` method, `dtList.Select` is an entirely different method: `Enumerable.Where`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `dtList.Select(...)` is a [linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.7.2) against `DataRow[]` (not `DataTable` at this point) so you use something like

```
var filtered = dr.Select(r => r["DesignTypeName"].ToString() != "Change Order");
```

**EDIT**

The above should use `.Where` instead of `.Select`, obviously.

Comment: If I do that now how can I access to column, after this I have something like this:  `var designItemName = currentDesignItem["DesignItemName"] as string;`, but now how can I access? Because I'm getting error: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'bool'

Comment: See the edit in the answer. The `Where` is the filter, the `Select` was a projection. Sorry about that.